# Reusable simpleType definition in SQL Server schema collection

Tags: sql-server, xsd, xml-schema-collection, xmlschema

I'm trying to create a reusable simpleType in an SQL Server XML schema collection but I'm getting an error. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xs:schema
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="SomethingUnique"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:simpleType name="dateTimeOrEmpty">
        <xs:union memberTypes="xs:dateTime">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SomeDate"/>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:union memberTypes="xs:dateTime">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:union>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                <xs:element name="OtherDate" type="dateTimeOrEmpty" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If I try to create an XML schema collection with this schema I get this error

> Reference to an undefined name 'dateTimeOrEmpty'

Is it possible to reuse the named simpleType definition or do I have to retype the entire simpleType definition for each element I was to use it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a namespace problem.  I think I understood this at one time, but now I just have to fiddle with it until it works.  EG

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION foo AS  
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xs:schema
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="SomethingUnique"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:s="SomethingUnique"
    >

    <xs:simpleType name="dateTimeOrEmpty">
        <xs:union memberTypes="xs:dateTime">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="RootType">
        <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SomeDate" type="s:dateTimeOrEmpty"/>
                <xs:element name="OtherDate" type="s:dateTimeOrEmpty" />
            </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Root" type="s:RootType"/>

</xs:schema>'
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized I was missing a name space reference after I posted this.